# android:windowNoTitle will not hide actionbar with appcompat-v7 21.0.0

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-appcompat

I updated appcompat-v7 to lollipop version(21.0.0)

then I can't hide ActionBar with following style that worked before.

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

I set it to specific activity.

```
<activity android:name=".NoActionBarActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"/>
```

When I use appcompat-v7 20.0.0 version, actionbar will be hidden as it is intended.

How can I hide actionbar with custom style with `AppCompat` version 21 library?

Comment: What do you mean by "it works well"? Your question doesn't describe what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I mean that actionbar will be hidden if I use version 20.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`@Chk0nDanger` your answer is true but you should use below code :

```
<style name="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
   <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
   <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

without parent element, everything will be white color (`textviews`,`buttons`,`chekcboxs`, etc)!

in your `manifest.xml` file :

```
    <activity android:name=".MyClass"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"
        />
```

**updated 2015 29 July**

make sure `android:windowNoTitle` should be replaced by `windowNoTitle` when Upgraded to `AppCompat v22.1.0`

Comment: make sure  *android:windowNoTitle* should be replaced by *windowNoTitle*  when Upgraded to AppCompat v22.1.0

Answer (score 10):

OK, I found the answer.

There is Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar theme in appcompat-v7:21.0.0.
It is defined as following.

```
<style name="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
   <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
   <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

There is no `android` prefix in `windowActionBar` attribute.

Comment: Everything became white color !